# Why am I overwriting all of my values in state with my object spread?

Tags: reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, setstate

In my handleChange function I use an object spread to get all prior key/vals from this.state and I add on a new value to the selectedCountry key. My issue is that I keep reassigning the countryFlags value which messes up my app's state. Am I missing something? I've really wrestled with this for hours and I cannot figure out the reason for this. Is it my overall implementation of setState. Thank you in advance for your observation.

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import FlagSelect from "./FlagSelect";


export default class FlagQuiz extends Component   {  
    constructor()  {
        super()
        this.state = {
            countryFlags: undefined,
            selectedCountry: ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
            .then(function(response, reject) { 
                return response.json()
            })
            .catch(() => console.log("nope"))
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({countryFlags: data})
            });

    }

    handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        // console.log(this.state)
        const newState = {...this.state}
        newState.selectedCountry = value
        // console.log(newState)

        ///STOP UPDATING THE countryFlgs!!
        this.setState({...this.state, selectedCountry: value})
        console.log(this.state)

    }

    render(){
        const flagStyle = {
            display: "block",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            width: "50%"
        }
        const src = this.state.countryFlags === undefined ? "" : this.state.countryFlags[0].flag
        const buttonStye = {
            background:"lightblue",
            color: "white",
            fontSize: "30px",
            float: "right"
        }
    const countries = this.state.countryFlags ? [
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length),
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length),
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length),
            Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length)
        ] : ""

        const fourCountries = () => {
            let flagselects = countries ? countries.map((countrynum) =>{
                return <FlagSelect 
                handleChange={this.handleChange} 
                checked={this.state.selectedCountry}
                key={countrynum}
                countryinfo={this.state.countryFlags[countrynum].name}/>
            }) : null

            return flagselects
        }

        return (
            <div>
            <form>
                <div className="form-check">
                {fourCountries()}
                <div className="form-group">
                <button style={buttonStye} >Guess</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </form>

                <h1 style={{textAlign:"center"}}>Flag Quiz</h1>
                <img src={src} alt="flag" style={flagStyle}
                />
                {this.state.countryFlags ? console.log(this.state.countryFlags.length): ""}
            </div>

        )
    }

}
```

My results are a selectedCountry but with a whole new set of randomized selection of countries from the countryFlags array.

Comment: You only need `this.setState({ selectedCountry: value })`. Nothing else is needed. Don't do things like `{ ... this.state }`.

Comment: Hey @Sulthan, from what I gathered earlier doesn't that override all of state with that returned state, or is react smart enough to only change that key?

Comment: What you are passing is *partial state*. React actuallly does `{...state, ...stateUpdate}` internally and safely (note that `setState` is asynchronous).

Answer (score 1):

Changing state is simple:

```
this.setState({ selectedCountry: value })
```

Nothing else is needed.

However, changing state will always cause a rerender. And I see a big problem with your rendering.

Everytime `render` is called, you will randomize your flags:

```
    const countries = this.state.countryFlags ? [
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length),
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length),
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length),
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.countryFlags.length)
    ] : ""
```

Therefore your UI will change.

`Render` is supposed to always return the same thing if properties and state have not changed. However, your `render` will always display different things depending on the random numbers.

You have to move your randomization to your state, for example:

```
.then((data) => {
    const countries = [
         Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length),
         Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length),
         Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length),
         Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)
    ]
    this.setState({ countryFlags: data, countries })
});
```

Comment: Wow, that totally makes sense now. I didn't know it was an ok practice to put logic in setState but that makes way more sense now. Also, thank you for your response earlier on the breakdown of setState's background workings.

Comment: @GabrielLemon It's not actually "logic", it's just data generated by your logic which you need to keep between rerenders.